# Chatter Bookmarks

Tags: visualforce, community, chatter

How to display chatter bookmarks in custom Visual Force page.

I have looked on some for connect API methods but I can't find the exact one. So please update me.

Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In Apex, use [ConnectApi.ChatterFeeds.getFeedElementsFromFeed()](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_ConnectAPI_ChatterFeeds_static_methods.htm#apex_ConnectAPI_ChatterFeeds_getFeedElementsFromFeed_2) with the feedType set to ConnectApi.FeedType.Bookmarks and the subjectId set to 'me' (since you can only request the bookmarks feed of the current, logged-in user).

Comment: Can you update how to display the bookmarks in visual force page. Just a simple snippet will be useful.